# Using a different number system on conventional programming languages

Tags: java, python, c, numbers

Let's say I don't need with the mainstream number system that starts at zero and increases or decreases infinitely. What I need is a cyclic number system that starts at 0 and ends at 5, pretty much like the angular system of a circle. So, if I do additions, it goes something like this:

```
0+1=1
1+1=2
2+1=3
3+1=4
4+1=5
5+1=0
```

Now, our programming languages use the traditional number system. Is there any workaround that if I type `5+1`, the programming language will give me 0 every time and not the 6 symbol? No matter, if that is a Python, C, D, or other programming solution.

Comment: That's a pretty useless number system.

Comment: No wonder that pay so little there. You can't earn more than 5!

Comment: There is only a 6% chance that you will find your answer here, martian person.

Comment: @iCodez You answered 35 seconds after my question was posted. How can you judge a number system that quickly?

Comment: What's the problem using base 6 instead?

Comment: @DoxyLover: Yeah, but nothing costs more than 5 either. Plus, if something is too expensive, wait for the price to go up 16% and now it's free.

Comment: Looks like the modulo-rest class Z//6 to me.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza base 6, `5 + 1 = 10`

Comment: @ArditS. maybe he has a group of 6 working for him

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Martians.

Comment: @owlstead Well then there are other systems for that. He doesn't have to use the base 5.

Comment: Base 6 Ardit, it would be base 5 if the martian person also does not understand the notion of zero.

Comment: @arditS. I'm just playing.  :)  However, what good is a number system with only 6 digits?  Besides, yours says I have 0 fingers.  How did I type this then??  I'm so confused... lol.

Comment: @iCodez What good is a number system with only 360 digits? Well, it's hell good, because we have circles. Maybe you shouldn't have closed the question...

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [arithmetic modulo 6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation):

```
for i in range(6):
    print('{}+1 = {}'.format(i, (i+1)%6))
```

yields

```
0+1 = 1
1+1 = 2
2+1 = 3
3+1 = 4
4+1 = 5
5+1 = 0
```

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that in C, instead of `%6`, the answer is `%6`. And in D, it's `%6`. And in Ruby, it's `%6`. And in bash, it's `%6`. And… (It's always worth learning as many languages as possible to see all the different ways to do things.)

Comment: Yes, but that does not look a very permanent solution. If I type 5+1 below your code, inside the same script, it will still give me 6.

Comment: In Python, numbers like `5` are immutable. You can not change its `__add__` method, for instance. So there is no way (without modifying Python itself) to make `5+1` evaluate to 0.

Comment: You can subclass `int` and override `__add__` and the like...

Comment: @kindall: True, but you can't make `5` an instance of the subclass. I think Ardit wants to literally type `5+1` and have it evaluate to `0`.